# How to Assign values of List

Tags: vb.net, xsl-fo

What iam doing is creating a PDF- File and returning bookings of the current week. There are booking for Monday, Thuesday, Wednesday and so on. I try to assign the bookings to his date. What i mean is. If there a booking for Monday, then the bookings should be assigned to that date. If bookings for thuesday, then assign the bookings of thuesday to that date.

To illustrate it:   [WeeklyBPlan](http://i48.tinypic.com/sw60ph.png)

As you can see on the Picture bookings for Montag(Monday) get assigned and bookings for Dienstag(Thuesday) get assigned.

My Problem is that with my Code only the first day(Monday) of the week is returned and all the bookings is assigned to that Date.

I think my Problem is `wbp.WeekDay = strCurrDay` or is something wrong with my .fo?

Please can anyone help me? How can i do what i want, like in the Picture?

```
Public Shared Function WeeklyBPlanPDFExport() As List(Of WeeklyBPlan)

        Dim allBookings As List(Of WeeklyBPlan) = New List(Of WeeklyBPlan)

        Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        Dim kw As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Now, , FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFourDays)
        If DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Now, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday) = 6 Then
            kw = kw + 1
        End If
        Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, ReturnDateForWeekNumber(kw))
        For i = 1 To 7
            Dim strCurrDay As String = ""

            strCurrDay = FormatDateTime(CurrDateFirstDay, DateFormat.LongDate)

            CurrDateFirstDay = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, CurrDateFirstDay)


            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT  d.SEATING, d.ROOMID, d.ID, d.PERSONS, d.ADDRESS+ ', ' + d.ROOMDESCRIPTION AS ROOMDESCRIPTION , d.EVENT,  p.VN + ' ' + p.NN AS NAME, CONVERT (char(5), d.FROM, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT (char(5), d.TO, 108) AS TIME, p.TEL FROM VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_DISPO AS d INNER JOIN PERSONAL AS p ON d.PERSONAL_ID = p.ID WHERE CONVERT(char, d.FROM, 104)='" & to_104(strCurrDay) & "'"
            Dim objRS As SqlDataReader
            Dim objRS2 As SqlDataReader
            objRS = SQLrunReaderWB(strSQL)

            If objRS.HasRows Then

                While objRS.Read()

                    Dim wbp = New WeeklyBPlan



                    wbp.WeekDay = strCurrDay

                    wbp.Raum = objRS("ROOMDESCRIPTION")
                    wbp.Zeit = objRS("TIME")



                    If Not IsDBNull(objRS("EVENT")) Then
                        wbp.Thema = objRS("EVENT")
                    End If

                    If Not IsDBNull(objRS("NAME")) Then
                        wbp.Mieter = objRS("NAME")
                    End If



                    wbp.Personen = objRS("PERSONS")
                    wbp.Bestuhlung = objRS("SEATING")



                    allBookings.Add(wbp)




                End While




            End If
        Next
        ConnWB.Close()

        Return allBookings


    End Function
```

MY XSL-FO:

`

```
                 <!--this defines a title level 1 -->



                    <fo:block

                            line-height="24pt"
                            space-after.optimum="15pt"
                            padding-top="3pt">
                      <xsl:value-of select=".//WeekDay" />
                    </fo:block>


                <!-- table start -->
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" border="solid" border-collapse="collapse" border-width="0.5pt">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="12mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                                <fo:table-column column-width="50mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                                <fo:table-column column-width="10mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="35mm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="35mm"/>
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block background-color="grey"
                      color="white" text-align="center">Room</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block background-color="grey"
                      color="white" text-align="center">Time</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>

                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block background-color="grey"
                      color="white" text-align="center">Event</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>

                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block background-color="grey"
                      color="white" text-align="center">Persons</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                           <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block background-color="grey"
                      color="white" text-align="center">Seating</fo:block>
                           </fo:table-cell>

                           </fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-row>
                      </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                      <xsl:for-each select=".//WochenBPlan">
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell  border-right-width="0.5pt" border-right-style="solid"  border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid" padding-right="6pt" padding-left="6pt" >
                                    <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt"  padding="2pt">
                                        <xsl:value-of select=".//Room" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border-right-width="0.5pt" border-right-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid">
                                    <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt"  padding="2pt"  text-align="center">
                                        <xsl:value-of select=".//Time" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>

                                <fo:table-cell border-right-width="0.5pt" border-right-style="solid"  border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid" padding-left="6pt" padding-right="6pt">

                                       <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt"  padding="2pt" wrap-option="no-wrap" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select=".//Event" />
                                       </fo:block>

                                </fo:table-cell>


                              <fo:table-cell border-right-width="0.5pt" border-right-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid">
                                <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt"  padding="2pt" text-align="center">
                                  <xsl:value-of select=".//Persons" />
                                </fo:block>
                              </fo:table-cell>
                              <fo:table-cell border-right-width="0.5pt" border-right-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid"> 
                                <fo:block  font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" padding="2pt" text-align="center">
                                  <xsl:value-of select=".//Seating" />
                                </fo:block>
                              </fo:table-cell>


                              </fo:table-row>

                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                  </fo:table>
                  <!-- table end -->




                <fo:block id="lastBlock"/>
            </fo:flow>`
```

WeekylyBPlan Class:

```
public class WochenBPlan
{
    public WochenBPlan()
    {

    }

    public string Raum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Erstellt { get { return DateTime.Now; } set { } }
    public string Zeit { get; set; }
    public string Bereich { get; set; }
    public string Thema { get; set; }
    public string Mieter { get; set; }
    public string Mieter_Tel { get; set; }
    public string Personen { get; set; }
    public string Bestuhlung { get; set; }
    public string Bemerkung { get; set; }
    public string Ausstattung { get; set; }
    public string WochenTag { get; set; }



}
```

Comment: Holy Sql Injection vulnerability, Batman. You really need to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to be honest, I don't have a ton of experience in writing C#, so I am gonna write your WochenBPlan class in VB for now, just to spare you the agony of reading my C# for now.

On a side note, given that your class really is just a structure as it doesn't have any functionality really associated it with it, you could just convert it to a public structure, but its all preference.

The thing that is bugging me is that you are declaring a new WeeklyBPlan but I think that for clarity and simplicity, you probably should write a few 'New' sub-procedures like...

```
     Public Class WochenBPlan 
      'I've learn that it is best to declare class variables private and then expose them through public properties as follows
       Private _Raum As String, _Zeit As String, _Bereich As String, _Thema As String
       Private _Mieter As String, _Mieter_Tel As String, _Personen As String
       Private _Bestuhlung As String, _Bemerkung As String, _Ausstattung As String
       Private _WochenTag As String, _Erstellt As DateTime

       Public Property Raum As String
         Get
            Return _Raum
         End Get
         Set(value As String)
           _Raum = value
         End Set
        End Property
       ' So on and so forth for the remaining....

      ' Adding some functionality

      ' Default Constructor
      Public Sub New()
       ' Set all private variables to what you want (I tend to set them to Nothing, unless I need them to be some value)
      End Sub


      Public Sub New(ByVal theDay As String, ByVal theRoom As String, ByVal theTime As String(I'm not sure what type you have that has), ByVal thePersons As String, ByVal theSeating As String)
     _WeekDay(Or the German word for it) = theDay
     _Raum = theRoom
     _Zeit = theTime
     _Personen = thePersons
     _Bestuhlung = theSeating
     ' Declare rest to nothing/null
     End Sub
    ' Add Whatever Else You May Want
      End Class
```

That will ensure that you get everything set in each loop, and then your second loop will be simplified down to...

```
         While objRS.Read()

                Dim wbp = New WeeklyBPlan(strCurrDay, objRS("ROOMDESCRIPTION"), objRS("TIME"),objRS("PERSONS"))


                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("EVENT")) Then
                    wbp.Thema = objRS("EVENT")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("NAME")) Then
                    wbp.Mieter = objRS("NAME")
                End If




                allBookings.Add(wbp)




            End While
```

I am not sure if this will work, but it very well could, so let me know if that does it, or I will continue to work until we figure it out. You could add those 'If' statements into the overloaded 'New' Statement and then you could just do allBookings.Add(New WeeklyBPlan(...))

Comment: hi, i tried but i think this is nt the problem. nothing changes if i do it like this

Comment: I will take another look at it tonight after I get done with dinner, sorry for the first suggestion not working.

Comment: I'm thankful that my mom is fluent in German, will make it easier to figure out the issue now that I know what all those words mean in the image you linked (I'm a very visual person).

Comment: Can you post the 'WeeklyBPlan' class or send it to me?  Wanna take a look at that real quick, made a console application, and your code above works fine on my system, so the issue I think lies somewhere else.

Comment: Updated my Question. Thank you very much for you efforts and merry christmas! :)

Comment: Hi, i tried it, but it does not work. I think the Problem lies in the XSL-FO. I tried to group the Bookings by the Date, but that does not work also.  There should be an option <xsl:for-each-group>, but somehow, that option is not available if i try to use it.. I really dont know how to solve that problem

Comment: Yeah, that must be the issue here, unfortunately, I'm not the best person to ask regarding XSL-FO, hopefully someone comes along and can help you out.